# Can't start gunicorn with systemd django

Tags: django, gunicorn, systemd, virtualenvwrapper

I'm new to `systemd`. just installed `lubuntu16.04`. 
I have the following `systemd` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=jcg
Group=jcg
WorkingDirectory=/home/jcg/venvs/baseball/baseball_stats
ExecStart=/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8001 baseball_stats.wsgi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get this error:

```
jcg@jcg-Inspiron-1011:/var/log$ systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-05-16 13:59:18 EDT; 9min ago
  Process: 681 ExecStart=/home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8001 baseball_stats.wsgi 
 Main PID: 681 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

May 16 13:59:18 jcg-Inspiron-1011 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
May 16 13:59:18 jcg-Inspiron-1011 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CH
May 16 13:59:18 jcg-Inspiron-1011 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 16 13:59:18 jcg-Inspiron-1011 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

But if I run this `gunicorn starts`:

```
(baseball) jcg@jcg-Inspiron-1011:~/venvs/baseball/baseball_stats$ /home/jcg/.virtualenvs/baseball/bin/gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8001 baseball_stats.wsgi
```

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: Working Directory doesn't seem to be same in your script and shell command. I hope that is just a typo.

Comment: Good catch.  I changed /.venvs to /venvs but same problem

Comment: doesn't journalctl give you anything more?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For future readers, my problem was caused by not having an environment variable set that was required by my django application. (settings.py reads the environment).  When invoking gunicorn from the command line, that environment variable was previously set.

When using systemd the following is necessary in the gunicorn.service file:

```
  [Service]
  Environment=SECRET_KEY=secret
```

Comment: For more clarification, Even if you have your environmental variables exported in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` you need to have the environment defined for the service. You can use those files by adding `EnviromentFile=home/user/.bash_profile` to the `[Service]` block.

Comment: After read any articles, it's works fine... thx for post the solution.

Comment: @calder.ty Just a correction: it's `EnvironmentFile=/home/user/.bash_profile` - notice the _n_ in  _Environment_ and the slash prepending the path in order to make it absolute.

Comment: You can set environment variables in wsgi file

Answer (score 0):

Do the following
First you have to create a service file in system

```
$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/python_django.service
```

Write the following code in service

```
[Unit]
Description = Python django service
After = network.target

[Service]
ExecStart = /etc/python/python_script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

then create a file `python_script.sh` with the following script in `/etc/python/`

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - -c /etc/python/config/python_django.py  python.wsgi:application
```

then give the permissions to that file

```
$ chmod +x python_script.sh
```

create a file `python_django.py` in `/etc/python/config` then put the following code

```
command = '/usr/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/home/user/{python_dir}'
bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
workers = 5
user = 'user'
```

then run this code

```
$ sudo systemctl enable python_django //it creates a symlink
$ sudo systemctl start python_django 
$ sudo systemctl status python_django
```

Now you can see the running service.

just check `http://{ip}:8000 || $ curl  "http://0.0.0.0:8000"`

Note: please make sure your gunicorn file exists in /usr/bin/gunicorn
Check it as `$ ls -l /usr/bin/gunicorn`